# Where in a Rails application is the RDoc title set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

Documentation generated for a Rails application by `rake doc:app` gets a default title of "*Rails Application Documentation*". The Rake sets this:

```
rdoc.title    = ENV['title'] || "Rails Application Documentation"
```

I can change this by doing

```
$ title='some other title' rake doc:app
```

However, I would like to set this in, say, `application.rb` or `environment'rb` but this doesn't appear to work.

Where should I set the title for RDoc in a Rails application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer by *K M Rakibul Islam*, a custom Rake task is one way to set a different title. I provided one in a new `lib/tasks/documentation.rake` file:

```
require 'rails/tasks'
namespace :doc do
  RDocTaskWithoutDescriptions.new("mydoc") { |rdoc|
   rdoc.rdoc_dir = 'doc/app'                                                                                                   
    rdoc.template = ENV['template'] if ENV['template']
    rdoc.title    = "My Application Documentation"
    rdoc.options << '--line-numbers'
    rdoc.options << '--charset' << 'utf-8'
    rdoc.rdoc_files.include('README.rdoc')
    rdoc.rdoc_files.include('app/**/*.rb')
    rdoc.rdoc_files.include('lib/**/*.rb')
  }   
end
```

This task is identical to the built-in one except for the line that sets the title. I found that the other answer generated to a `html` directory instead of `doc/app` and ran a lot of other things too. This task is executed by

```
$ rake doc:mydoc
```

This is based on the [original Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8c752c7ac739d5a86d4136ab1e9d0142c4041e58/railties/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake) which I note was [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cd7cc5254b090ccbb84dcee4408a5acede25ef2a) on Feb 6th 2015. That means an update to the latest Rails will break this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Rakefile` like this:

```
RDoc::Task.new :rdoc do |rdoc|
  rdoc.main = "README.rdoc"

  #change this to fit your needs
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include("README.rdoc", "doc/*.rdoc", "app/**/*.rb", "lib/*.rb", "config/**/*.rb")

  #set your title
  rdoc.title = "App Documentation"
  rdoc.options << "--all" 
end
```

And, then just:

```
rake rdoc
```

See the [RDoc::Task documentation](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Task.html) for details.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just set it without having to create a new rake task? That's hardly _DRY_ - if that's the only way then I am very surprised...

Comment: Not that I know! btw, when you say, `this doesn't appear to work.`, how did you set title in application and environment files? Try adding a @title instance variable in your application.rb file if you already did not do that.

Comment: `ENV['title'] = 'my title'` in `environment.rb`. Also tried `@title = 'my title'` in `application.rb` but that didn't work either. I guess it'll have to be a custom rake task.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like you need a rake task as i showed in my answer